# Getting information from the Moodle API as a student

Tags: node.js, moodle, moodle-api

I'm currently a student at a University and I'm using Moodle everyday.
I would like to access some information that is available to me (For example, information of the classes I'm taking, Which assignments are due and when , etc)

I did some research regarding Moodle's API but it all seemed geared toward the power user who actually runs Moodle (My University).

Is there an easy way for me as a student to get the information?

My application uses Node.js

Comment: If there is no student api you must try somethings like parse html and ...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If your university has enabled Web Services for the mobile app, you can generate your own API token and call the Web Services used by the mobile app. If the latter are not enabled, you have to get in touch with your administrator to get Web Services access.

**Demo using moodle.org**

First, let's get an API token (replace `$USERNAME` with your username, and `$PASSWORD` with your password):

```
$ curl -d username="$USERNAME" -d password="$PASSWORD" 'https://moodle.org/login/token.php?service=moodle_mobile_app'
{
  "token":"SNIPTOKEN",
  "privatetoken":"SNIPPRIVATE"
}
```

Next, we need your `userid`, it will be used throughout other web services call. You can obtain your `userid` by calling the web service `core_webservice_get_site_info`. Make sure to replace `$TOKEN` with the token you obtained above.

```
$ curl -d wstoken="$TOKEN" -d wsfunction=core_webservice_get_site_info 'https://moodle.org/webservice/rest/server.php?moodlewsrestformat=json' | python -m json.tool | grep userid
"userid": 1451616,
```

Now that you have your `userid`, we can request the courses that you are enrolled in.

```
$ curl -d wstoken="$TOKEN" -d wsfunction=core_enrol_get_users_courses -d userid=1451616 'https://moodle.org/webservice/rest/server.php?moodlewsrestformat=json' | python -m json.tool
[
    {
        ...snip...
        "fullname": "Moodle in English",
        "id": 5,
        ...snip...
    },
    {
        ...snip...
        "fullname": "Moodle en fran\u00e7ais",
        "id": 20,
        ...snip...
    },
    {
        ...snip...
        "fullname": "Moodle Certification",
        "id": 48,
        ...snip...
    }
]
```

**Recap'**

*Pre-requisites:*

- The **Mobile App** webservices must be enabled
- The **REST** protocol must be enabled
- You need an API token

*Querying:*

- Requests are made to `YOURHOST/webservice/rest/server.php?moodlewsrestformat=json`.
- Requests must be `POST` requests
- Requests must contain `wstoken`: Your token
- Requests must contain `wsfunction`: The function you are calling
- Requests type must be: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

**More**

I've greatly simplified how this works and what alternatives there are, but this should get you started. You will likely be interested in looking at the developer documentation to get more information about the available web services:

- [Web Services developer documentation](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_services)
- [Web Services functions list](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Web_service_API_functions) (May not be updated frequently)

Comment: what is the purpose of privatetoken? which REST API return along with the "token"

Comment: I believe it is used to automatically login a Mobile user on the website site, as such that users do not need to re-enter their login and passwords to access the Moodle site.