# what is the use privatetoken in Moodle REST API response?

Tags: php, rest, moodle

I am using Moodle core REST API and I am following [this Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44652206/getting-information-from-the-moodle-api-as-a-student) answer for my login request.  login end-point is working successfully.

API Request

```
$ curl -d username="fmcorz" -d password="$PASSWORD" 'https://moodle.org/login/token.php?service=moodle_mobile_app'
```

Response

```
{
  "token":"SNIPTOKEN",
  "privatetoken":"SNIPPRIVATE"
}
```

I am using token to get User ID and other stuff. But I want to know what is the main purpose of privatetoken?

according to my understanding this will use if moodle installation is on **Https** and "token" will we used when we use **http** but not sure as I have only **http** based server

please help to understand this so I can choose best available token to implement Moodle REST API.

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the token [docs](https://moodleschema.zoola.io/tables/external_tokens.html), `privatetoken` is only sent when the token is first created and should be saved by the client. The [source](https://github.com/moodle/moodle/blob/master/login/token.php) says it's only sent when the connection is https and the user is not an admin. So I assume it's an edge thing as it [should be returned only in very special circumstances](https://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-56737). It sounds like it's the [Random all-time valid token](https://docs.moodle.org/dev/External_services_security#Random_all-time_valid_token) which can only be sent over https and not for an admin user.